# Sort an array which results in maximum product of elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming

I am working on a problem which involves taking an integer array as an input from the user. The program calculates product of the elements of the array. The calculation goes as follows:
for eg, let the input be 56, 61, 2. Then the program first performs `56 * 61 = 3416`, then `modulo 3416 with 199 = 33`. Now take the next element in the array, i.e., 2 and multiply it with the 33 = 66. The result would be `3416 + 33 = 3482`. This is the calculation of the `isotopes atom`.
Now if we can rearrange the elements of the array, i.e., 61, 2, 56; we could achieve the maximum product as follows:

```
61 * 2 = 122
122 * 56 = 6832
6832 + 122 = 6954
```

I have written program which plainly calculate the product of the input array but now I want to sort array as mentioned above. My program is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
public class codevita1 {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        int num = 0;
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt (args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println ("Arguments not enough");
        }
        int arr[] = new int[num];
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            arr[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        new codevita1().calcEnery (arr);
    }

    private int calcEnergy (int elements[]) {
    int energy = 0;
    int t = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            energy = (elements[i] * elements[++i]);
        } else {
            energy += (t * elements[i]);
        }
        t = energy % 199;
    }
    return energy;
}
}
```

I have searched for dynamic programming and divide and conquer algorithm but I could not understand which algorithm will help me achieve my task. Please help me out with respect to which algorithm should I use and how?

Comment: Can you explain little bit more the line of your post about "Now if we can rearrange the elements of the array, i.e., 61, 2, 56; we could achieve the maximum product as follows:" beacuase before this line already you having "The result would be 3416 + 33 = 3482"

Comment: Observe the sequence of elements before the first result, i.e., 56, 61, 2 and observe the sequence of elements after the first result, i.e., 61, 2, 56. The operation is performed in sequential manner only (as in array).

Comment: You should perhaps remove the English explanation of the algorithm, because I couldn't make much sense of it in one reading... You have the code in `calcEnergy` method, which I assume is correct, and seems clear enough for somebody who doesn't really know Java, too. So just show the example results for different orders of numbers. Or write pseudocode in addition to Java.

Comment: Perhaps I could have given the whole definition but its too lengthy so I have tried my best to explain the algorithm in shortest of the form. 50% of the work is done; just the point remains how to I re-arrange the array so as to achieve the maximum product of the elements.

Comment: I'm fairly sure your calcEnergy formula is incorrect as I get the same value for every permutation. Seems to be missing a modulus in there somewhere and perhaps other things. Depending on what the code looks like afterwords, I have an approach in mind that might work.

Comment: rearranging the formula in the loop a bit `energy = (energy * (1 + elements[i]))` it is clear that the result does not depend on the order of the array elements.

Comment: Missing modulo by 199. Actually a piece of code missing. Sorry for the inconvenience I will update it soon. I observed this is

Comment: Please review the program I have updated the method calcEnergy()

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach is to check every permutation, and it take O(n!) time.

Also you may notice that (a%199 * b)%199 = (a * b) %199
It allows us to check every way to split set of numbers in two nearly equal subsets.
When we check on of ways to split, we can calculate t which remains after calculation energy for first subset as just product of all numbers in first subset % 199 it will remain constant regardless of order of elements in the subset.
Then we can recursively calculate optimal order for both subsets.

There are C(n,n/2) ways to split n numbers in two subset if order of subsets does matter. C(n,n/2) < 2^n so total number of operation is less than 2^n * 2 * 2^(n/2) * 4 * 2^(n/4) * 8 * 2^(n/8) *... * 2 ^ (log(n)/2) * 2^(2) * 2 ^ (log(n)) * 2 ^ 1 which is ~ 2^(2*n + 2*log(n)) which is O(2^n) so still very slow but better than n!

I suspect that it's may be much better to split in more subsets (more precisely sqrt(n) subsets sqrt(n) elements in each) but didn't yet calculate complexity for this case.